# Unable to create temporary view on SPARK dataframes

Tags: apache-spark

Here is the sample code

```
spark-shell --master yarn 
val hive_location = "hive_meta_loc"
val spark =org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder().appName("WNGDEVICES").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hive_location").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()  
val rawdata = spark.sql("SELECT *  from <table name>") 
rawdata.createOrReplaceTempView("Rawdata")
```

when I perform this operation I am getting the following error

[image: ERROR SNAP]

Comment: Please replace screenshot with text. Images are no good for users with visual impairments (which often depend on [screen readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader)), provide poor experience on mobile devices, and are not accessible to search engines.

Comment: This looks like permission issue. Can you do a count on that table or get first record of that table?

Comment: I am able to view the data using the dataframe by saying rawdata.show

Comment: This was permmissions issue , Thanks @morfious902002